# VBA for Excel - Updating a Variable in One Sub by Returning It From Another Sub or Function

Tags: excel, vba

I have looked at many different articles and Stack Overflow posts on this and I seem to be missing something.

In short, I have a long procedure.

It mostly adds columns and sets those columns to a relative formula (i.e. FormulaR1C1 or Formula2R1C1) as well as conduct many Find & Replaces on columns.

It is meant to help automate cleaning up some product description data.

Regardless, it is getting quite long and I have set up Integer variables to keep track of the locations of some critical columns so that I can compute the Relative References for the aforementioned formulas.

I want to be able to call another procedure or function that updates all of these variables that store the critical column locations because they change a lot since columns are being added and taken away.

This will make the code much easier to follow and write.

It is getting sloppy because I essentially have been copying and pasting these large blocks of code that are referenced multiple times for the same exact purpose.

Also, I am trying to stay within the same module because this code is meant to be distributed and I am not advanced enough to make a VBA package or solution yet.

Since my main procedure (i.e. Enrichment_Automation) is really long and not in the cleanest state I will post what I have for the sub procedure (or function) below. As of now, it updates the value for the integer variables mktngdesc_col_loc and shortdesc_col_loc, but these new values do not return to the main procedure.

Also, a lot is commented out because I was debugging to try and get a couple to work the way I wanted.

Please let me know if you need more information, want me to post all/more code, or anything else.
Thank you for your help in advance!!!

```
Function Reset_Main_Column_Locations(shortdesc_col_loc As Variant, ByVal brand_col_loc As Integer, ByVal catno_col_loc As Integer, ByVal mktngdesc_col_loc As Integer, ByVal metadesc_col_loc As Integer)

    'Dim shortdesc_col_loc As Integer
    'Dim brand_col_loc As Integer
    'Dim catno_col_loc As Integer
    'Dim mktngdesc_col_loc As Integer
    'Dim metadesc_col_loc As Integer
    
    
    
    
    'Finds Marketing Desc Column
    Cells.find(What:="ItemMarketingDescription_en", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2 _
                , LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    
    'Sets column variable to the current marketing desc location
    mktngdesc_col_loc = ActiveCell.Column
    
    
    'Finds Short Description column
    Cells.find(What:="ItemShortDescription_en", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2 _
                , LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    
    'Resets the variable that stores the Short Description location to the current location of that column
    shortdesc_col_loc = ActiveCell.Column
    'Enrichment_Automation shortdesc_col_loc:=ActiveCell.Column
    
    'Finds Brand Column
    'Cells.find(What:="ItemBrand", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2 _
    '            , LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    '            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    
    'Resets the variable that stores the Brand location to the current location of that column
    'Set brand_col_loc = ActiveCell.Column
    
    'Finds Manufacturer Name column
    'Cells.find(What:="ItemManufacturerName", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2 _
    '            , LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    '            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    
    'Resets the variable that stores the Manufacturer Name location to the current location of that column
    'Set mfctr_col_loc = ActiveCell.Column
    
    'Finds Catalog Number Column
    'Cells.find(What:="ItemCatalogNumber", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2 _
    '            , LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    '            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
           
    'Resets the variable that stores the Catalog Number location to the current location of that column
    'Set catno_col_loc = ActiveCell.Column
    
    
    'Call Enrichment_Automation(shortdesc_col_loc, brand_col_loc, catno_col_loc, mktngdesc_col_loc, metadesc_col_loc)
    

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're having scoping issues. There are a few ways to solve this, each with their own pros and cons.

### ByRef Parameters

```vb
Function Reset_Main_Column_Locations(ByRef shortdesc_col_loc As Variant, ...
```

Specifying parameters as ByRef will pass a reference to the actual value and any modifications made inside the function will be reflected outside the function.

### Global Variables

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim shortdesc_col_loc as Long
----------------------------------------
```

Defining your variables in the outer scope of the module -- in general, at the very top of the module, outside of any function/sub -- will allow any of the subs/functions within that module to access and potentially modify them.

Used correctly, either of the two solutions above can provide a simple solution to your problem. However, they both introduce action at a distance, which can make your program harder to debug and occasionally result in surprising behavior. To avoid potential gotchas, I would suggest using a third option instead:

### Functionize Find

If you frequently need to retrieve the column number of a value in a particular row, you could simply write a function to do this for you.

```vb
Public Function ColumnOfValue(rRange As Range, Val As Variant) As Long
    Dim Found As Range
    Set Found = rRange.Find(Val, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Found Is Nothing Then
        ColumnOfValue = -1
    Else
        ColumnOfValue = Found.Column
    End If
End Function
```

You could then set whatever variable(s) you needed by calling it from the main body of your subroutine like this:

```vb
mktngdesc_col_loc = ColumnOfValue(activesheet.rows(1), "ItemMarketingDescription_en")
shortdesc_col_loc = ColumnOfValue(activesheet.rows(1), "ItemShortDescription_en")
```

Comment: Thank you @Plentyofcoffee! I will try out your recommendations and then let you know if I am able to make it work. I am going to start off with the ByRef Parameter because that seems like an easy fix. Then, when I have things in a better place I will create the "Functionize Find" like you recommended. Is this the correct way to call the function I currently have from the main procedure?: `Call Reset_Main_Column_Locations(shortdesc_col_loc, brand_col_loc, catno_col_loc, mktngdesc_col_loc, metadesc_col_loc)` I am only testing the shortdesc_col_loc right now to make sure it works first.

Comment: it works!!! Thank you so much!!! There are few other blocks of code that I can do this with now too! I have implemented some already and it is definitely going to make things easier to track and more concise. Thanks again!!! I will comment again if I run into issues with the Function you posted.

Comment: Fantastic, I'm glad it worked. If my solution helped you, could you mark it as the answer?

Comment: By the way, if you're using the function in the way shown by your previous comment, I would suggest changing it from a Function to a Sub. In general, Subs are expected to "do things" and Functions are expected to return values.

Comment: Will do! Thanks again!